# Bisimulation, bisimulation equivalence and simulation equivalence?

Tags: simulation, transition-systems

I got a little confused with these 3 concepts. Is there a difference between bisimulation and bisimulation equivalence and if yes, then what is it? Also, if we say that the LTS's X and Y are bisimilar, this implies they are simulation equivalent, right? Please, someone, clarify.

Comment: This might come in handly for you https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~hs/Aktivitaeten/2011_Vino/Talks/Morning/02_Stephan-Merz_Bisimulation.pdf

Comment: @Sudara that's a 403